# CSS Ribbon not working properly in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

can anyone figure out why this isn't displaying properly in IE 9? Here's what it looks like: 
[image: looks like] 
and here's what it 
should look like: [image: should look like]

Here's my code -- any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

html

```
<div class="addl-colors-container">
<span class="addl-colors">
::before
"Multiple Options""
::after
</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .addl-colors-container{
    width:105px;
    height:105px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    pointer-events:none;
    margin:-10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
span.addl-colors {
    background:linear-gradient(#25aeca 0%, #5fc8c2 100%);
    box-shadow:0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    top:20px;
    line-height:22px;
    width:147px;
    right:-16px;
    transform:rotate(-37deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-37deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-37deg);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    border-top-right-radius:75px;
    border-top-left-radius:75px;
    }
span.addl-colors:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    border-left:3px solid #25aeca;
    border-right:3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
    border-top:3px solid #25aeca;
}
span.addl-colors:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0%;
    top:100%;
    z-index:-1px;
    border-right:3px solid #25aeca;
    border-left:3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
    border-top:3px solid #25aeca;
}
```

This is displayed inside another box. It was a lot of code so I didn't paste it but if it's needed, please let me know and I will post. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked if every css you use is officially supported by IE9? Have a look at caniuse.com

Comment: cool, thanks! @kalsowerus

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately linear-gradient not found in internet explorer, I had the same problem and y solv putting a simple background before the linear gradient

like this:

```
span.addl-colors {
    background: #25aeca;
    background:linear-gradient(#25aeca 0%, #5fc8c2 100%);
    ...
}
```